# JPA createNamedQuery syntax

Tags: java, jpa, orm, named-query, jpa-2.0

In Pro JPA 2 (Apress) book, I have seen examples like,

```
EntityManager em;
Long count = em.createNamedQuery(countQueryName, Long.class).getSingleResult();
```

But, the [api](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) , hopefully applied to JPA 2.0, shows the syntax as

```
createNamedQuery(String name) 
Parameters:
name - the name of a query defined in metadata
```

with a single parameter. The book uses the type extensively, so what am I missing?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java EE 5 uses JPA 1 and Java EE 6 uses JPA 2. Here's the method you're looking for:

[createNamedQuery(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Class resultClass)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)):

> Create an instance of `TypedQuery` for executing a Java Persistence
>   query language named query. The select list of the query must contain
>   only a single item, which must be assignable to the type specified by
>   the `resultClass` argument.
>
> *Parameters*: 
>   `name` - the name of a query defined in metadata 
>   `resultClass` - the type of the query result
>
> *Returns*: the new query instance
>
> *Throws*: `IllegalArgumentException` - if a query has not been defined with the given name or if the query string is found to be invalid or if the query result is found to not be assignable to the specified type
>
> *Since*: Java Persistence 2.0

Comment: thanks.. I need to wait 6 min to accept the answer, SO says :-)

Comment: invalid url can you provide another or summerize it here

Comment: @shareef, I have updated the answer, but in the future you can edit and update the answers yourself and fix broken links, etc.